# using gradient but without mixing color

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I don't know if that is a stupid question or something like that but i want a `div` to be filled certain percent by one color and remaining part by other.

And the gradient property

```
.div{
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, #fff 50%);
}
```

Results into [image]

```
.div{
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 28%, #fff 72%);
}
```

And this results into [image]

i want to get the white and black not to mix and be seperated on all percentages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
.div{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, black 50%, white 0%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, black 50%, white 0%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, black 50%, white 0%);
    background: linear-gradient(left, black 50%, white 0%);
}
```

Comment: I know this already but still don't get one certain thing: how does this work? Would be wonderful if someone could explain it. Because my head won't come up with sth to explain it :)

Answer (score 7):

When you did:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 28%, #fff 72%);
```

it means:
Black (#000) from 0% to 28%, then start a gradient to white (#fff) until reach 72% and after this gradient, use white until the end.

So you can use:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 28%, #fff 28%);
```

This way you'll get: black from 0 to 28%, a gradient from 28% to 28% (it means, no gradient), and white from 28% to the end. So you'll get only back and white, without the gradient between them.

Comment: or just have #fff 0%

Answer (score 4):

Why do you want to use gradient in first place if you dont want them to mix?

Anyway this is working:

```
div{
     height: 200px;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 50%, black 0%);
     background: -linear-gradient(left, white 50%, black 0%);
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 50%, black 0%);
}
```

you can put any value for white. It wont mix.

Answer (score 3):

do you mean :

```css
div{
     background: linear-gradient(to right, #000 28%, transparent 28%, transparent 72%,#fff 72%);
  color:green
}
body {
  background:yellow
    }
```

```html
<div> lorem ipsum blabla lorem ipsum blabla lorem ipsum blabla lorem ipsum blabla</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Give Multiple gradient Color to a Div 
Use this Css

Check this Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/2pcccd2p/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/dineshkanivu/2pcccd2p/

```
   background: #ff474a; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff474a 0%, #7a2e68 50%, #0cf900 51%, #0a0784 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff474a), color-stop(50%,#7a2e68), color-stop(51%,#0cf900), color-stop(100%,#0a0784)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ff474a 0%,#7a2e68 50%,#0cf900 51%,#0a0784 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ff474a 0%,#7a2e68 50%,#0cf900 51%,#0a0784 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ff474a 0%,#7a2e68 50%,#0cf900 51%,#0a0784 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ff474a 0%,#7a2e68 50%,#0cf900 51%,#0a0784 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff474a', endColorstr='#0a0784',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/eUS/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient
You can:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    red 20%,
    orange 20% 40%,
    yellow 40% 60%,
    green 60% 80%,
    blue 80%
  );
}
```

body {
background: linear-gradient(
to right,
red (end pos)%,
orange (start pos)% (end pos)0%,
yellow (start pos)% (end pos)%,
green (start pos)% (end pos)%,
(end pos) 80%
);
}