# CSS striped background with linear-gradient without blur between strips

Tags: css

I want a striped background like this:

[image]

I have tried with linear-gradient, but it adds some blur between strips:

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, red, white, green, white, violet)
}
```

```html
<div>Foo text</div>
```

How to remove the blur?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using gradient but without mixing color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29116149/using-gradient-but-without-mixing-color)

Comment: The most adapted answer to your case would be [this answer from the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29116550/7393478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add value for color stops and make sure the last value of one color is **the same** as first of the next color.

```css
div {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(135deg, red 30%, white 30% 40%, green 40% 60%, white 60% 70%, violet 70%)
}
```

```html
<div>Foo text</div>
```

Here is a different idea with skew transformation:

```css
div {
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
   z-index:0;
}
div:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-20px;
  right:-20px;
  bottom:0;
  background:
   linear-gradient(red,red)       left  ,
   linear-gradient(green,green)   center,
   linear-gradient(violet,violet) right ;
  background-size:25% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:skew(135deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div>Foo text</div>
```

Comment: You are a geniuos, thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

To have lines you should specify the same color at start and end points:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right,
   red, red 10px,
   rgba(0,0,0,0) 10px,
   rgba(0,0,0,0) 20px,
   blue 20px, blue 30px,
   rgba(0,0,0,0) 30px,
   rgba(0,0,0,0) 40px,
   green 40px, green 50px,
   rgba(0,0,0,0) 50px,
   rgba(0,0,0,0) 60px
 );
 background-size: 60px 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, red, red 10px, green 10px, green 20px, violet 20px, violet 30px)
}
```

```html
<div>Foo text</div>
```